# Hyphen causing a line break in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make sure that the date 2012-13-12 always ends up on one line.
If I use / as a date separator it works but the '-'-sign (not very surprised) makes the date end up on two rows.

```
<div class="someclass">
      around  lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium 2012-13-12 lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium 
</div>
```

and

```
.someclass { width:40mm; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjK6D/

Any suggestions?

Comment: try: css `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Not getting you here..

Comment: Is the problem that it causes a line break or that it does *not* cause a line break? The title says one but the question text says other.

Comment: thanks, however for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: I miss the line break. The date ends up on two rows if it is to the right in the 40 mm area

Comment: "I miss the line break" doesn't make sense, but I'll interpret the rest so that you *don't* want the line break there.

Answer (score 6):

use css with "white-space:nowrap;"

or (older method) use tag "nobr"
example 1:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .nobr { white-space:nowrap; }
</style>
<div>
around  lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium  around  lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium <span class='nobr'> 2012-13-12 </span>lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium 
</div>
```

example two:

```
<div>
    around  lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium  around  lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium <nobr> 2012-13-12 </nobr>lorem Ipsium lorem Ipsium 
</div>
```

Comment: Good opportunity to use HTML5 `<time>` here, too

Comment: I believe that the <nobr> tag is depricated, so the first example is a much better solution than the second

Comment: There’s no need to include spaces into the `span` element.

Comment: You are right,  it was for the example.